# Set HTTP Session alive time programmatically during session creation

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, httpsession

I have a JSP-Servlet based Web application where I would like to achieve the following scenario.

1. I need to set the HTTP session alive time programmatically when I am creating the session.
2. I need to invalidate the session even though the user is actively using the application, which is why the classic Session Time out configurations in the deployment descriptor and session.setMaxInactiveInterval() will not work for me.
   Thus, When I am creating the session, I need to make sure I provide the exact amount of time for which the session will be active.

Let me know how I can achieve this scenario. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: And why can't you use `HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(int seconds)`? if you don't want to use a default `session-timeout` in your web.xml, you can just set the timeout for each session by using that method...

Comment: @QuakeCore Haven't tried anything yet. Also, I can not user session-timeout in web.xml file or HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(int seconds) because I want the user session to be ended even though the user is active. I am trying to achieve 'Absolute Session Timeout'.

Comment: what is your condition for invalidating the session? if you are not going with the default behavior which is the user being inactive for a specific amount of time, then you must have some sort of a logic to invalidate the sessions...

Comment: @QuakeCore The condition for invalidating the session is when the current time of the system reaches a particular value. For example, I want to invalidate the session when the current time is 6.00 PM. But the time at which session needs to be invalidated is configurable and changes dynamically within my application which is why I need to invalidate the session programmatically.

Comment: What you could do is just calling `HttpSession.invalidate()` when a request comes to your server after 6:00 PM. I strongly suggest that you rationalize the requirements before starting with the actual implementation, then things will start to clear out